# How to swap 2 items in a list in Python?

Tags: python

Wondering how to swap two items in a list (or an array) in Python?

Some example code showing the expected output:

```
def swap_name(name_list): 
""" (list of str) -> NoneType 

Modify name_list so that the first name and last name are swapped. 
            
>>> name = ['Tommy', 'Jason'] 
>>> swap_name(name) 
>>> name 
['Jason', 'Tommy'] 

""" 
# My Answer which is not complete and i don't know how to complete it or how to correct it. I tried in every way but it didn't work...I need your help

for i in range (len (name_list)):
    name_list[i] = [name_list[1] , name_list[0]]
```

Comment: What if the list contains more than two entries?

Comment: Python lists have a `.reverse()` method.

Comment: `swap_name(name_list)` is even completely equivalent to `name_list.reverse()`.

Answer (score 8):

In python you can swap elements with one expression: `left, right = right, left`

```
>>> name = ['Tommy', 'Jason']
>>> name[0], name[1] = name[1], name[0]
>>> name
['Jason', 'Tommy']
```

Comment: The right answer (if it's about swapping items rather than just reversing a list)

Comment: To swap the final two items in any list, use this: `name[-2], name[-1] = name[-1], name[-2]`.

Comment: If error `TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations`, then use: `name = list(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can do:

```
name_list.reverse()
```

If this is homework, you're typically expected to show something more like this (otherwise, this would be an exercise in using python standard methods, rather than understanding a swap algorithm):

```
temp = name_list[0]
name_list[0] = name_list[1]
name_list[1] = temp
```

These are, however, all dependent on your list only having 2 items in it. Your `for` loop makes me get the feeling that your data structure is more complex than that. Can you show us some example inputs and outputs?